# Rails no stack trace but 400 error in nginx log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stack-trace, http-status-code-400

I'm sending an POST to rails with an image so it's a multi part form and it often works just fine.

But sometime I get a nginx log 400 error for the POST but nothing in the rails log to give me information on why the 400 happened vs 200.

This happens like 50% of the time but the other 50% I get a 200 and the image is stored just fine.

Any idea where to look next to see the real reason behind the 400? I don't have enough information at this point to debug. 400 just means Mal-formed post but what is Mal formed?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Look in nginx error log; you might need to enable it:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/